# Norm of a certain operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

I am stuck on a particular problem. I consider the operator
$$A:\mathbf{L}^2[-1,1]\longrightarrow\mathbf{L}^2[-1,1]:f\mapsto Af$$
where I define $Af(t) = t^2f(t)$, and I want to calculate its norm. I already have the following partial results:

- Since $t^4 \leq 1$,$\forall f\in\mathbf{L}^2[-1,1]$:
  $$\|Af\|_2^2 = \displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1 t^4|f(t)|^2dt
                \leq \displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1 |f(t)|^2dt 
             =   \|f\|_2^2$$
  so $\|A\|\leq 1$;
- On the other hand, if I consider $f$ to be the constant $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$-function, then obviously $\|f\|_2 = 1$ and it's easy to verify that
  $$\|Af\|_2^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\limits_{-1}^1 t^4dt
                   = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[\dfrac{t^5}{5}\right]_{-1}^1
       = \dfrac{1}{5}$$
  So certainly $\|A\|\geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Now what exactly is $\|A\|$?

Comment: Try $f$ equal to the characteristic function of $[1-1/n,1]$ suitability normalised.

Comment: Yes, that one does the trick. \|A\| = 1